# Postgresql trigger insert on another table after update and update other tables

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, postgresql-13

I have a `post` table and when I soft delete a post I want to also soft delete rows on the `comment` and `post_image` tables using a trigger.

I have an intermediate table `deleted_post` where I insert the `post_id` and `deleted_at` after the soft deletion of `post`:

```
| post_id | deleted_at |
```

This is the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_deleted_post
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON "post"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE deleted_post_update_trigger_fnc();
```

And this is the function that is called by the trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deleted_post_update_trigger_fnc()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
-- insert into deleted_post
INSERT INTO "deleted_post" ( "post_id", "deleted_at")
VALUES(NEW."id",NEW."deleted_at");
-- delete post comments
UPDATE comment c
SET deleted_at = NEW.deleted_at
WHERE (c.post_id = NEW.id AND c.deleted_at is null);
-- delete post image
UPDATE post_image pi
SET deleted_at = NEW.deleted_at
WHERE (pi.post_id = NEW.id AND pi.deleted_at is null);
RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

When I edit a post on `post` table I get back this error:

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "path": "$",
    "code": "constraint-violation"
  },
    "message": "Not-NULL violation. null value in column \"deleted_at\" of relation \"deleted_post\" violates not-null constraint"
}
```

and:

```
description: null
exec_status: "FatalError"
hint: "Consider using an AFTER trigger instead of a BEFORE trigger to propagate changes to other rows."
message: "tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command"
```

I cannot spot where the issue resides in the trigger.

#### Questions

- Is this trigger safe for many transactions? Hundreds of post could be deleted from users at the same time.
- Is there a big risk that some transactions might fail?
- What is the issue with my trigger / function failing?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE ....`) of the involved tables to your question by hitting the [edit] link? There seems to be some kind of constraint violation. I'm not fluent with triggers and functions on PostgreSQL , but we do have some resident DBAs who might be able to assist. Adding details allows the community to provide you with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the CREATE command for the tables involved? Also, when you say "When I edit a post on post table I get back this error:" what is the command that you launch?